# Trying to get column counts having data using openxm(C#)

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to count  header columns only having data in excel sheet using openxml(c#).
For example if  the data is present in A1,D1,F1, then the count should be 3  and not 6 (i.e A to F).
Please suggest how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

To know if a cell contains a value check if `CellValue` is not null. The following should work for you:

```
Row row1 = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault();
int counter = 0;
foreach (Cell cell in row1.Elements<Cell>())
{
    if (cell.CellValue != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cell.CellReference);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this and it working fine for me.

```
foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
{
    if (cell.CellValue != null)
    {
        var NumberOfCol = datatable.Columns.Count;
        DataRow tempRow = datatable.NewRow();
        for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfCol; k++)
        {
            if (tempRow[k] != null)
            {
                tempRow[k] = row.Count() > k ? GetValue(spreadsheet, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(k)) : "";
            }
            else
            {
                tempRow[k] = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `DataRow` and `DataTable`? You want to count the number of headings, where is the count?